# Key validation in spring cloud contract tests

Tags: json, spring, groovy, spring-cloud-contract

How can I verify key format from json response in spring cloud contract tests?

Let's say I have json response that looks like:

```
{
  "products": {
    "0": {
      "type": "food",
      "name": "pizza"
    },
    "9": {
      "type": "drink",
      "name": "wine"
    }
  }
}
```

And contract test looks like:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

Contract.make {
    description 'Dynamic key example'
    request {
        method 'GET'
        urlPath '/products/all'
    }

    response {
        status 200
        headers {
            contentType applicationJsonUtf8()
        }
        body(
                [
                        "products": [
                                "0": [
                                        "type": $(anyOf("food", "drinks")),
                                        "name"  : $(nonBlank()),
                                ]
                        ]
                ]
        )
    }
}
```

Product ids (`"0"` and `"9"`) can take any positive integer values. I want to validate product ids in contract test. But if I replace `"0"` in contract with `($(consumer("0"), producer(regex("^\\d+\$"))))` it compiles. But tests, based on this contract will create following assertion

```
assertThatJson(parsedJson).field("['products']").field("['DslProperty(clientValue:0, serverValue:\\d+)']").field("['name']").matches(".+");
```

Which contains `DslProperty` instead of a key. And of course, such test will fail.

Any ideas how to solve this problem? Is it possible at all?

P.S. I don't have possibility to change protocol

Comment: Why does it fail if you do what you mentioned?

Comment: Not exactly. on producer service side it creates assertion like `assertThatJson(parsedJson).field("['products']").field("['DslProperty(clientValue:0, serverValue:\\d+)']").field("['name']").matches("\\d+");` As you can see key read as `DslProperty`, which fails the test

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Spring Cloud Contract?

Comment: Original question was written with the use of 2.2.3.RELEASE. Just checked on the latest (3.0.3) version - same situation and errors.

Comment: Can you please file an issue?